# Troubles with conditional looping

Tags: python, pandas

I have an initial dataframe:

```
 A | B | C | D        |  E
one| AA| 4 | 24.07.19 |25.07.19
two| AA| 1 | 24.07.19 |25.07.19
one| AB| 3 | 24.07.19 |25.07.19
two| AC| 1 | 24.07.19 |25.07.19
two| AD| 1 | 24.07.19 |25.07.19
one| AD| 2 | 24.07.19 |25.07.19
```

Items in B column can have only two parameters from A column (one, two). I'm trying to create plots for each item in B column.
The idea is, that IF item has both two parameters, do one kind of plot if no => another.

But I stuck on the problem that whenever I try to make a condition I receive or The Truth value is ambiguous error or only the else-part works even if the item has two parameters.

How can it sound in pseudocode:

IF item has 'one' AND 'two' in A column:
    do smth
ELSE (IF item has 'one' OR 'two' in A column):
    do another

My code is:

```
items = df['A'].unique()

for item in items:
    aa= df[df['B']==item][df['A'].isin(['one','two'])].reset_index(drop=True)
    aa = aa[aa['C']<500].reset_index(drop=True)
    if (aa['A'].values[0]=='one') & (aa['A'].values[0]=='two'):
       print('yes')
    else:
       print('no')
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Column B doesn't have values "one" and "two". Column B has values "AA", "AB"...

Comment: There are way too many variables used here that you haven't included in description. Try creating [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by "IF item has both two parameters, do one kind of plot if no => another"? When you work with a dataframe some rows fill the condition, and others don't. If you want to create a plot for each row, you would need to iterate over the rows, each row at time. And please notice that if `aa['A'].values[0]` equals 'one', then it can never be equal to 'two' at the same time, as you wrote in the condition.

Comment: @Aryerez  I mean that if item has both one and two values in column A, then we print one plot. if an item contains only one of the values from column A, then we print another plot. So basically I just can't get how to specify the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will get you out of the error:

```
aa = df[(df['B']==item)&(df['A'].isin(['one','two']))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

But you still have:

```
if (aa['A'].values[0]=='one') & (aa['A'].values[0]=='two'):
    ...
```

Which is never `True` as you are testing same thing to be both `one` and `two`.

That being said you might want to go with `or` there:

```
if (aa['A'].values[0]=='one') | (aa['A'].values[0]=='two'):
    ...
```

**EDIT**

I'm guessing this is what you are looking for:

```
for item in items:
    aa= df[(df['B']==item)&(df['A'].isin(['one','two']))].reset_index(drop=True)
    aa = aa[aa['C']<500].reset_index(drop=True)
    if ('one' in aa['A'].values) & ('two' in aa['A'].values):
       print('yes')
    else:
       print('no')

#yes
#no
#no
#yes
```

Comment: well, I get then a ploblem similar to old mine - I will get only yes since there are items that have only one feature

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many values of column "A" exist for each value in column "B", you can do:

```
counts = df[['A', 'B']].drop_duplicates().groupby('B').count().reset_index().rename({'A': 'A_counts'}, axis=1)
```

Then you can merge `counts` into `df` with:

```
df = df.merge(counts, how='left')
```

And in `df` you will have a column `A_counts` which states for each value in column 'B' how many items of column 'A' it has, so you can do conditions on that new column.